# Unreliable behavior of has_many with :inverse_of option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Take example from [rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Bi-directional+associations):

```
class Dungeon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :traps, :inverse_of => :dungeon
  has_one :evil_wizard, :inverse_of => :dungeon
end

class Trap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dungeon, :inverse_of => :traps
end

class EvilWizard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dungeon, :inverse_of => :evil_wizard
end

Dungeon.create!.traps.create!
d = Dungeon.first
t = d.traps.first
d.level == t.dungeon.level # => true
d.level = 10
```

The following expression returns false, though it expected to return true (at least for Rails 3.1):

```
d.level == t.dungeon.level # => false
```

What's wrong with `:inverse_of`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a bug, but when you work with association like with relation, `inverse_of` does not work:

```
d.traps.where('1=1')[0].dungeon.object_id != d.object_id
d.traps.first.dungeon.object_id != d.object_id
```

Though when you use it like array, `inverse_of` behaves properly:

```
d.traps.map { |t| t.dungeon.object_id } == [d.object_id]
d.traps[0].dungeon.object_id == d.object_id
```

It works properly when you create an object:

```
d.traps.build.dungeon.object_id == object_id
```

It does not work for belong_to with has_many (and it specified somewhere in documentation):

```
t.dungeon.tasks[0].object_id != t.object_id
```

So to avoid surprises from `inverse_of`

1. Use `[0]` instead of `first`
2. Don't implement the logic to depend on it (some other guy may replace your `select(&:some_predicate?)` with `some_scope` and your code will no longer work)
3. Don't use `inverse_of` for `belongs_to` with `has_many` on the opposite end of the association